# Install xcache on Amazon linux AMI

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I use EC2 amazon with Amazon linux AMI and i installed latest php56 etc (XAMPP)
When I try to install xcache with :

```
yum install php-xcache xcache-admin
```

Gives me error:
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

I used `sudo yum install php56-mbstring`
But did not work.

On another instance I have ubuntu and it works fine.
I am new at a firm and my project was on Amazon linux AMI, now they want to switch it to another hosting, I was wondering is there much difference in systems and will everything work on ubuntu same as Amazon linux AMI, because I would rather use ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: Packages that begin with php are php 5.3 versions. If you want to use a 5.6 package, install `php56-xcache` . I should add that if you are using this for the optimizer features, its no longer necessary. Optimizer has been built in.

Comment: I figure all that out, but project is old like 2-3 years and there is a lot of xcache_get() for example functions built in it. Also there is no php56-xcache or I can not find it and intall it :(

Comment: With default setting in amazon linux image, there is only php5.3 (php-xcache) and php5.4 (php54-xcache). So uninstall `php-common` first (which is for php53). Use `yum list installed |grep php` to list all php package, I guess you need remove other php5.3 packages as well. Then try to manually install php56-xcache

Comment: @SitaReturn In that case, you will will have to install it via pecl. `pecl install xcache` You will probably need dev packages installed if you dont already.